# Loop Quantum Gravity and Gauge theory

Tags: gauge-theory, loop-quantum-gravity

1. Are there any connection between [Loop Quantum Gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) and [Gauge theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory)? If so, how does the gauge theory is described?
2. When exactly does the spin network of the foam is created in the era around the big bang?
3. What is the mechanism of the Big Bounce?
4. Does the foam of the space time is preserved even when the universe is crunching?

Comment: I think your questions are answered in Pietro Doná, Simone Speziale "Introductory lectures to loop quantum gravity" [arXiv:1007.0402](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0402). As per the Big Bounce, it appears using Bohr compactified reals reproduce the mechanism...I can look up references on this later if you want.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Yes, I'm glad if I could see the reference .

Comment: Ah, here we are, the paper showing how Bohr compactification saves the universe: V. Husain, O. Winkler "On Singularity Resolution in Quantum Gravity" [arXiv:gr-qc/0312094](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0312094).